# Electrical flux through a ring-like surface

Tags: electric-fields

I am preparing for a retake exam in electromagnetism, in the exam paper a question asks : "Consider a ring-like surface of internal radius $r_{int} $= 3nm and external
radius $r_{ext} $=5nm and an electric field of magnitude E=5r (where
$[E/r]=[N/(C nm)]$). Calculate the electric field flux through the ring,
taking E parallel to dA."

In the answer we substitute dA to be $2\pi r dr $
why is this not $\pi r^2?$

Comment: Sorry for the no understanding of Mathjax

Answer (score 1):

The area of a circle of radius $r$ is $A=\pi r^2$. But that's not what $dA$ is supposed to represent. $dA$ is the *change* in area when the radius $r$ of a circle is increased by an amount $dr$. We find this differential by taking the derivative of the area with respect to the radius:

$$\frac{dA}{dr}=2\pi r$$

which means, in turn, that $dA=2\pi r \;dr$.